# auto switch problem on music on(android version lollipop )

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, 5.1-lollipop

my android 5.1 lollipop switches to the next song if it experiences a shake so its frustrating when you are listening to music with the phone in my pocket, it auto switches to next song if it detects any movement. so how do l stop that?

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this problem  "Go to Settings - Accessibility - switch off Air-shuffle function for Music, FM radio, Pictures, Camera."